# Program works just fine in IDE, once build is done, it throws java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, path

Back story to this is that I have a GODEX printer that I use to print barcodes. Everything works just fine while running within IDE(Netbeans)

However, once I do build, and try to run .jar file, I am getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Error itself:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       ...
>       ...
>       ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at IMS.Godex.EZioLib$API.(EZioLib.java:13)

and here is the line 13 in EZioLib.java:

```
String path = API.class.getResource("/").getPath().replaceAll("%20", " ").substring(1) + "Ezio64.dll";
```

any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the runtime environment in the IDE is the same as if you run it from the terminal? For example, there are some paths set up in the IDE that are probably missing if you just run it from the terminal.

Comment: Include the runtime dependency that you want for your jar to execute , it may do the trick.